# Object recognition of a set of objects

Tags: computer-vision, object-recognition

In a computer vision project, the image I want to process can be partitioned in "zones" containining multiple products of the same kind.

Provided that I can retrieve image information of all the possible kinds of product, I need to detect which kind is present in each zone, without the need to detect the position of each single product. In summary, I need to recognize "sets of products".

As additional info, the products have not a rigid shape, they are not oriented in the same manner and luminosity changes (so I am basically searching for shape, orientation and luminosity invariant approaches).

The reliable info I can exploit is that the products logos - or parts of them - are often visible and the products are quite colorful.

I would like to know about possible approaches that exploit the fact that I know the zones partition and approaches that do not exploit it.

Comment: You can use SIFT,SURF.

Comment: Already tried without much success.